# Add new column in temporary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I m checking unique number and putting the data in temporary table.
Below table show VarientSKU and and it is unique or not.
Now I want to join this table with another table. For this I need unique column and in my table [ItemId] is unique table. So i wanted to add [ItemId] in that temporary table

[image]

```
alter Proc spIsUnique
@columnname nvarchar(max),
@tablename nvarchar(max)

As
Begin
declare @result nvarchar(max) 
set @result = 'select ItemId,IIf (count(VariantSKU)>1 or 
count(VariantSKU)=0,''False'',''True'') as [IsUnique-check] 
        INTO ##dq_IsUnique from '+@tablename+' 
        group by '+@columnname+';'

print @result



exec sp_executesql @result

End
```

I received this error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 185
Column 'Product.ItemId' is invalid in the select list because it is not 
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

And when I used both @Columnname and ItemID in groupby...it shows all unique value but few are not unique value
Please solve this..

Comment: `And when I used both @Columnname and ItemID in groupby...it shows all true value. Please solve this..` So what is the issue ? You already solve it

Comment: Trying to use dynamic SQL like that is a serious mistake and you simply don't need it. If you want to group by an arbitrary column just *don't* use stored procedures. This isn't code reuse - the reusable code is the *execution plan* produced by a query, not the query itself

Comment: @Squirrel edited..see it

Comment: As for the query itself, it doesn't make any sense. You are grouping by some column yet expect *individual* values from other columns to appear? What are you *really* trying to do? Most likely there are other, better ways to do it. Don't explain what you tried, explain what you wanted as a result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos...This is just some part of it..
and I need dynamic sql

Comment: @Awesome if you don't ask what you want, you won't get an answer. The only thing that's clear is that this query won't work

Comment: @Awesome btw if you need to perform aggregations like this, you need an actual table, not a temporary table. Even if you intend to discard the data after processing.

Comment: please [don't post text as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/57475)

Comment: It work when there is only two column..Varientsku and ISunique-check
but when I add Itemid it doesn't work..
So suggest me the way how it work

Comment: @Tanner didn't get you

Comment: @Awesome Your table output is text based, so copy the text and post it as text. It would be more useful as text if someone wants to use your sample data to create a solution as they can copy and paste the text you post, but they can't copy and paste the text if it's in an image.

Comment: In the given example you have two columns in the table so if your table variable is holding the same table name then obviously `Itemid` is not a column of that table if it's from another table then you have to joins the table where it exists.

Comment: @Susang it is from sametable

Comment: @Tanner table was so long that's why

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  is completely right here. This is a SQL injection nightmare. And why are you using a temporary table (especially a global one), is going to be awful for performance. We really need to understand your full goal here. I can't believe it's as simple as "I need to dynamically put the count of groups within a table into a Temproary."Table

Comment: Your sql query is invalid - plain and simple. What is it that you are trying to achieve (as in the final outcome?) http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data but, maybe MAX or MIN function works for you.

```
declare @result nvarchar(max) 
set @result = 'select MAX(ItemId) ItemId ,IIf (count(VariantSKU)>1 or 
count(VariantSKU)=0,''False'',''True'') as [IsUnique-check] 
        INTO ##dq_IsUnique from '+@tablename+' 
        group by '+@columnname+';'
```